Why a moving charge creates a rotating magnetic field around itself?
I want to understand the why using relativity, since it helps see in a more intuitive manner what is going on.
So, when we see Lorentz transformation and how it manipulates spacetime diagrams, there will be a hyperbolic rotation effect when an object moves. This hyperbolic rotation in spacetime can also be seen in terms of classical rotation in spacetime.(You can visualize this rotation by mentally rotating the entire spacetime diagram around an axis corresponding to the relative velocity between the two frames.)

(Image taken from the video of ScienceClic English channel about Lorentz transformation)
My question is if we replace that apple in the image with a charged particle, can we see the rotational vectors as the magnetic vectors? So essentially the electric fields are undergoing the classical rotation of the  Minkowski spacetime diagram and that rotational effect will be attributed to the magnetic field, thus answering my question? So the electric fields themselves are causing this effect but in a more complex manner, thus it was assigned to the magnetic field?
for context this is what the video said exactly:Electric field creates a force which accelerates charged particles, while the magnetic field makes them turn... These two situations are analogous... Just like the magnetic field, the electric field makes the particles turn only in hyperbolic rotations within spacetime... The electric field is the time version of the magnetic field
also when i said the hyperbolic rotation are analogus to the classical ones in space time...it was said in the video exactly like this at 9:15 :the  lorenz transformations are indeed analogus to rotations they are hyperbolic rotations.
